# cURL post request php to spring

Tags: php, spring, curl, post

I have to send array of a file to a spring server using PHP and cURL.

This is spring controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload/teacher" ,method = RequestMethod.POST) 
public HttpStatus uploadFiles(@RequestParam("files") MultipartFile[] inputFiles, 
                              @RequestParam("assignmentID") String assignmentID) throws IOException { ... }
```

PHP cURL:

```
<?php 
$filenames = array(pathfile1, pathfile2);

$postparameters = array(
  'files' =>  array(
                    new CURLFile($filenames[0], "text/plain", pathinfo($filenames[0], PATHINFO_BASENAME)),
                    new CURLFile($filenames[1], "text/plain", pathinfo($filenames[1], PATHINFO_BASENAME))
                  ),
  'assignmentID' => "0008"         
  );

print_r($postparameters);


//init curl
$url = "http://localhost:8090/upload/teacher";


$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => $url,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_POST => true,
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postparameters,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Content-Type: multipart/form-data"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

but with this code the backend does not receive anything.

if I send the curl request from the terminal, it works:

```
 curl -F files=@"pathfile1","pathfile2" -F assignmentID="1" http://localhost:8090/upload/teacher
```

it also works on postman:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mo3yg.png][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAYQO.png)

can someone tell me why if the backend does not receive the files when I run the request from php?

Comment: did you add :   @CrossOrigin(origins = "http:// yourphp host)  https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cors

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you annotate your spring controller method with  `@CrossOrigin` ?

```
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload/teacher" ,method = RequestMethod.POST) 
public HttpStatus uploadFiles(@RequestParam("files") MultipartFile[] inputFiles, 
                              @RequestParam("assignmentID") String assignmentID) throws IOException { ... }
```